# Adding a computed observable via the prototype to a constructor function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout.js 2.0 and I'm trying to extend the prototype of the constructor function I've created by adding a computed observable but its throwing up "self.IsSubDomain is not a function". How do I solve this error? Is there another way to extend a constructor function to solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/StrandedPirate/J44S4/3/

Note: I know I could define the computed observable inside the constructor function's closure but I'm building an automated code generator for knockout view models and I need to be able to extend my objects through the prototype property.

Comment: I guess it is not that easily possible. The thing is that the `computed` is a function that has the following signature:   `ko.computed(Func<T>, Object)` Where Object is an **instance** that is passed into the computation function's `this` context.

Comment: I tried this too but it didn't work: `SiteModel.prototype.fullDomainName = ko.computed(function () {
 ...
}, SiteModel.prototype);` I also noticed that the function is executing during page load which I think is the heart of the issue. It should only execute after an instance of the object is created. Is there a way to modify the knockout code to prevent execution of the function in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also [answered this in the forum](http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/msg/38d064334060b276).

Here's one way to do it ([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/J44S4/29/)):

```
<div data-bind="text: fullDomainName">test</div>
<script>
function SiteModel(rootUrl, data) {
    var self = this;
    self.rootUrl = rootUrl;
    self.DomainName = ko.observable(data.DomainName);
    self.IsSubDomain = ko.observable(data.IsSubDomain);
    self.fullDomainName = ko.computed(self.fullDomainName, self);
}

SiteModel.prototype.fullDomainName = function () {
    if (this.IsSubDomain() && this.DomainName()) { // bombs out here with "self.IsSubDomain is not a function"
        return this.DomainName() + ".myCompanyWebsite.com";
    }
    else {
        return this.DomainName();
   }
}; 

var temp = new SiteModel("someurl", { DomainName: "extraCool" });

ko.applyBindings(temp);
</script>
```

I've defined the function in the prototype and made it a computed 
observable in the constructor.

Here's a way to do it a more generic way ([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/XEez7/)):

```
<div data-bind="text: fullDomainName">test</div>
<script>
Function.prototype.computed = function() {
    this.isComputed = true;
    return this;
};
Object.prototype.makeComputeds = function() {
    for (var prop in this) {
        if (this[prop] && this[prop].isComputed) {
            this[prop] = ko.computed(this[prop], this, {deferEvaluation:true});
        }
    }
};

function SiteModel(rootUrl, data) {
    var self = this;
    self.rootUrl = rootUrl;
    self.DomainName = ko.observable(data.DomainName);
    self.IsSubDomain = ko.observable(data.IsSubDomain);
    self.makeComputeds();
}

SiteModel.prototype.fullDomainName = function () {
    if (this.IsSubDomain() && this.DomainName()) { // bombs out here with "self.IsSubDomain is not a function"
        return this.DomainName() + ".myCompanyWebsite.com";
    }
    else {
        return this.DomainName();
   }
}.computed();

var temp = new SiteModel("someurl", { DomainName: "extraCool" });

ko.applyBindings(temp);
</script>
```

The underlying read function of the computed *will* be shared via the prototype 
although the actual computed property won't. I suppose there could be 
confusion if you created some objects and then changed the function in 
the prototype. New objects would use the new function, but old objects 
wouldn't.

Since computed observables are properties, you shouldn't expect to 
be able to add them to existing objects through the prototype.

Comment: Your second fiddle might be a good way to do this, but your right, I shouldn't be trying to add properties to the prototype they should remain in the constructor function since they will be instanced.