# How to split Knockout view model to multiple files

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I had a long Javascript file with Knockout view model and related classes.

I wanted to split it into several files (one file per class) but experienced problems with Knockout.
Probably I did something wrong.

I have not found a simple solution on Stackoverflow so I decided to share my own solution (below).
It may look simple and obvious but I hope it could help developers less experienced in Javascript.

I've seen this question: [Splitting knockout view model into multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13799231/1131855) but it did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

My (very simple) solution is this.

ViewModel.js

```
$(function () {


    function ViewModel() {

        var self = this;

        //.....

        self.someObservable= ko.observable();

        //.....          

       self.init = function () {

           var someObject = new esd.model.SomeObject(param1, param2);
           self.someObservable(someObject);
       }

       self.init(); //Running the init code


 }

 var esd = esd || {};
 esd.model = esd.model || {};
 esd.model.viewModel = new ViewModel();
 ko.applyBindings(esd.model.viewModel);

});
```

SomeObject.js

```
var esd = esd || {};
esd.model = esd.model || {};

esd.model.SomeObject= function(param1, param2) {
    var self = this;

    //.....
};
```

Comment: There's really no need for calling you var esd = esd || {} and the esd.model = esd.model || {} every time you have a file. Also, you shouldn't set your 'class' declaration as the object of esd.model...just var SomeObject = function(...) {} then set esd.model.someObject = new SomeObject(...)

Comment: @beauXjames - I would prefer to have namespaces for 'class' declarations, just like it is in C#

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: SomeObject is not defined