# viewModel computed functions on the prototype using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, prototype, computed-observable

I am using using the knockout.js library, which helps with data-binding. So I keep getting the error that my variables are not defined inside a computed function which is on we viewModel prototype. I know this is because the computed function is changing the context of "this" to the Window, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to change back to the root(viewModel).The method I am referring to is "Messages" in the javascript. That being said, how do I change the context back to the viewModel?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
p#title.col-xs-12.bg-primary.text-center
  | Tic - Tac - Toe!
div.col-xs-3.bg-info
  div.bg-primary.controls
    span
      button.btn.btn-default(data-bind="click:StartMessage.bind($root)")
        | New Game
      p#message.lead(data-bind="text:Messages.bind($root)()")
table.bg-success(style="table-layout:fixed;")
  tr#row1
    td(data-bind="click:Messages.bind($root)")
    td &nbsp
    td &nbsp
  tr#row2
    td &nbsp 
    td &nbsp
    td &nbsp
  tr#row3
    td &nbsp 
    td &nbsp
    td &nbsp
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var message = (function(){
  function Message(){
   this.main = ko.observable(true);
   this.welcome = "Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe! This is a 2 player game. Click New Game to play!"
   this.turn = ", its your turn."
   this.win = ", you won!"
   this.draw = "It's a draw..."
  }
  return Message;
})()

var players = (function(){
  function Players(){
    this.player1 = ko.observable(true);
    this.player2 = ko.observable(false);
  }
  return Players;
})()

var aBox = (function(){
  function ABox(){
    this.symbol = ko.observable(" ")
  }

  return ABox;
})()

var viewModel = (function(){
  function ViewModel(){
    this.GameMessage = new message();
    this.thePlayers = new players();
    this.r1c1 = new aBox();
    this.r1c2 = new aBox();
    this.r1c3 = new aBox();
    this.r2c1 = new aBox();
    this.r2c2 = new aBox();
    this.r2c3 = new aBox();
    this.r3c1 = new aBox();
    this.r3c2 = new aBox();
    this.r3c3 = new aBox();

  }

/**************************************** 
 ************* Messages *****************
 ****************************************/ 

  ViewModel.prototype.StartMessage = function(){

     this.GameMessage.main(false)
  }

  ViewModel.prototype.Messages = ko.computed(function(){

    if(this.GameMessage.main()){
      return this.GameMessage.welcome;
    }
    else if(this.thePlayers.player1()){
      this.thePlayers.player1(false);
      this.thePlayers.player2(true);
      return "Player 1"+this.GameMessage.turn;

    }
    else if(this.thePlayers.player2())
      this.thePlayers.player1(true);
      this.thePlayers.player2(false);
      return "Player 2"+this.GameMessage.turn;
  },ViewModel)

  return ViewModel;
})()

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel())
```

I have experimented with changing the context to "viewModel" as shown,$root, and "this."

If you are wondering what the method is trying to accomplish, when the NEW MESSAGE button is clicked, it will trigger a message to be shown. Then if the `<td>` is clicked, it will display a different message in the place of the previous one.

Comment: Thanks I added it, i am using knockout.js for data binding

Comment: Is there a reason you have `Messages` in the prototype? I think since this computed is going to be a read only, you should be able to just make messages a property on the object itself.  Or create a `getMessages` on the prototype that accesses the computed.

Comment: So the reason I have it on the prototype is because I don't want to take up more space then I need to. I also heard it was best practice to do so. For that reason I don't want to have any functions on the object itself. Is theres way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure about adding them to the prototype, but I would say that if you're going to do it this way, and you want to have the right context - take the `ko.computed` off of `messages` and add it to the constructor:
`ko.computed(ViewModel.prototype.messages, this)`  Something like that.

Comment: so would I set that equal to an anonymous function? Im not quite sure how to use that on my method

Comment: yeah good point, trying out that code doesn't quite work.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289251/adding-a-computed-observable-via-the-prototype-to-a-constructor-function
He is doing it similarly, except doing `ko.computed(this.messages, this)`

Comment: Thanks. with your help I found a solution. I don't know how to mark your answer as correct though since you answered as a comment!

Comment: no problem, glad you found something that worked! :D

Comment: Thanks my friend I appreciate you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ko.computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) function include a second parameter that [allows to bind the computed function this to whichever object you specify](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#managing-this). (Behind the scenes it simply uses [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply))

So, when you're defining your computed in the prototype, you simply have to bind the computed to `this`, like so:

```
ViewModel.prototype.Messages = ko.computed(function(){
  // your function code
  }, this);
```

Remember that, as you're working with a prototype, `this` refers to the object instance you're interested in.